# Magento admin login 404 only at specific location

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We have been unable to log in to our magento admin panel for a few months now, but this isn't a standard 404 issue.

After logging in with correct username/password, we get redirected to a 404 page.  The strange thing is, it only happens from office WIFI, not over 4G or at our developers office.  This occurs on our dev server, not live (live logs in just fine)

Our developers have tried creating a new development environment on a new server but the issue is still occurring.

I have tried disabling all firewalls and cannot see anything in router settings which would cause this, anyone had a similar issue or can suggest a solution?

Comment: Please check .htaccess file

Comment: Already checked

Comment: Do you see the standard magento 404 page?

Comment: No, it doesn't redirect to our 404 page, it just shows a chrome/firefox/ie 404 page not found page

Answer (score 0):

Check your .xml files. You might been redirected to another module url showing the 404 error and check if module is currently actived. This would explain why you still have the same issue even when you're changing server, house, country etc etc.

Comment: Hello,  Thanks for the answer, although I said the issue is only occurring in our office, not anywhere else

Comment: Do you host the system locally? Another thing I would check would be the .htaccess for this module to see any redirects. Not the one located in root cause you're telling me everything is working properly, its only on this module.

Comment: Hello,  We do not host locally.  Which .htaccess file are you referring to?  I am able to access the admin panel with no issues if I connect through a free VPN

Comment: The main .htaccess located at root. for you to be able to see this file you have to log in with FTP

Comment: But you said in your previous comment 'not the one located in root'

Comment: Yes sorry you're right. Look for other htaccess redirects regarding this modules. These are usually located at the root folder of every module. So if your problem is within admin, then I would look into adminhtml